# I cannot get the location in google map where my code as below

Tags: javascript, html

This code I found it in Google developer, and I try to compile it, but it not work at all. I want to know what is wrong with this code, If I follow all the step from sample source code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place details</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?    v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316),
    zoom: 15
  });

  var request = {
    reference: 'CnRkAAAAGnBVNFDeQoOQHzgdOpOqJNV7K9-c5IQrWFUYD9TNhUmz5-    aHhfqyKH0zmAcUlkqVCrpaKcV8ZjGQKzB6GXxtzUYcP-muHafGsmW-    1CwjTPBCmK43AZpAwW0FRtQDQADj3H2bzwwHVIXlQAiccm7r4xIQmjt_Oqm2FejWpBxLWs3L_RoUbharABi5FMnKnzm    RL2TGju6UA4k'
  };

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(place.name);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
      });
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: do you have your keys setup with google API

Comment: That meant: reference:'....' is the key needed?

Comment: i have not seen the maps api key being set like that IMHO

Comment: So,what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Anyone can me with this problem, please?